# Gmail CC Field Shortcut or Always Visible

Tags: gmail

I've been searching for a way to access the CC field on GMail quickly. However, seems like there's no official shortcut (besides doing mad TAB TAB TAB TAB TAB TAB ENTER). There was a userscript published on lifehacker http://lifehacker.com/393844/always-show-gmails-cc-field-user-script that doesn't work anymore.

Anyone knows an alternative?

**Update**
Also disabling all the javascript/ajax functionality that gmail provides by default is **not** an option. So no "Basic HTML". Sorry.

Comment: Yes, I think your only option would be to update your script. But it does seem very complicated and unfortunately I wasn't able to do it quickly.

Answer (score 13):

If you’re using Chrome on a Mac, you can press:

- <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to add CC recipients;
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to add BCC recipients.

Comment: This also works for me on Firefox for Mac

Answer (score 6):

There is actually an official shortcut but it is kind of hidden. Try pressing the keys <kbd>b</kbd> or <kbd>d</kbd> to compose your message instead of <kbd>c</kbd>.

Source: [Google Operating System](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2010/11/undocumented-gmail-shortcuts-for.html)

Comment: Careful, though: when replying to a message, if you unfocus with Esc, and then press c, b, or d, it will try to open a "compose new message" window. If you had already written text, it will alert you, though. Bottom line, this doesn't work for replies. Shame.

Comment: `b` currently does nothing for me, and `d` composes in a new window

Answer (score 4):

If you enable the "Custom keyboard shortcuts" in the Labs, one of the options you can set is "Compose and show Cc field". Using this will open a new Compose editor with the CC field open.

Doesn't help with replies, though. And since it's a Lab feature it could get turned off any time.

It sounds like a feature that should be [requested](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/static.py?page=suggestions.cs).

Answer (score 2):

This is a very old topic and as far as I see, Google is still deaf about, so I decided to post my solution just for reference.

I'm a big fan of AutoHotKey and this is my Firefox script for Gmail replies (just press <kbd>F2</kbd> after filling the "to" field):

```
;Firefox
#IfWinActive ahk_class MozillaWindowClass
F2::    Send {tab}{tab}{tab}{tab}{tab}{tab}{enter}
    sleep 100
    Send ^{home}{delete}
    Return
```

Answer (score 1):

Scroll down your Gmail page and click on *Basic view*. Now compose. It cuts down on Gmail’s functionality, but it always displays the CC/BCC fields.

[Direct link to basic HTML view](https://mail.google.com/mail/?ui=html&zy=h).

Comment: hehe... +1 :) Goal achieved :D

Comment: Sorry, but I need a solution that doesn't rip off all of the gmail functionality.

Comment: It doesn't really rip off "all" of the gmail functionality? :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, as of now (6/2020) in Windows, if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> while composing a new message or replying to a new message, the CC field will un-collapse and the cursor will be right where it needs to be for you to type a CC address.

Likewise, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> in that situation will un-collapse the BCC field and place your cursor there.

Answer (score 0):

You can also install [this](https://userstyles.org/styles/157256/gmail-always-show-cc) Stylish userstyle. This will prevent the CC field from collapsing.

[image]

Comment: How does this help?

Comment: See my changes.